# React Native Error Occur, Someone Know About This Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 240
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ABI for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 240
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ABI for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

```
at makeError (D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)        
at D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\React Native Applications\FirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Please Give Solution About This Error

Answer (score 0):

So, if your project arises this type of error in the React-Native application, just open `android/app/build.gradle` Line: 240, remove this line

`def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)`

And paste the below code.

`def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)`